# Get reference to downloaded image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use `AFNetworking` to download images for cells. Then i want to pass that image (not URL, but image) to detail controller. Obviously, i could pass an URL and download image again, but i want to increase performance and pass image. My problem is, how to get reference to cell image? I have `NSInteger`  called `currentIndex`, that hold reference to current row. But how can i "find" current image for specific cell? Neither `didSelectRowForIndexPath` or `prepareForSegue` method hold reference to current cell.

This is how i set image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

// Image

```
[cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:news.urlImage];
```

Comment: It checks before downloading it again if it's already in cache. If you want to get more info, you can look into AFNetworking (in UIImageView+AFNetworking.m) for the method `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` and the part about `AFImageDownloader` and `AFImageRequestCache`.

Comment: As it is cached so when you will pass the url to detailController, it will not download it again , it will just fetch from the cache.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan okay, how to get reference to current cell when i want to pass image?

Comment: you can get the selectedIndex of cell in diSelectRowForIndexPath and save it and when the prepareForSegue is called , use the selected index and get the selected cell.From its imageview get the image and pass it to the detailController. perhaps helpful :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow And see the managing selections section from this I guess this is better.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan i know how to hold current index, thank you. But how exactly can i get reference to current cell?

Comment: @Injectios because it firstly downloaded image from url then set. I dont have image when app launch, only URL's

Comment: Sorry, bad connection, what I mean is - you are using -setImageWithURL inside your cells to load from URL, why you are worring about doing the same in your ViewController's view? Isn't it the same, and isn't it cache data?

Comment: @Injectios because i will download same image again, instead of passing image that already downloaded. Therefore it will spend time for download

Comment: But in cell it is executed so many times (when you scrolling), isn't it caching image uniqely for URL?

Comment: @Injectios yes it is. My problem i how to get refference to specific downloaded image (matched with cell user tap).

Comment: in didSelectRow, execute cell = tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip and get cell.imageView.image OR add UIGestureRecognizer on cell and execute when tap - delegate to viewController - cellDidReceiveTap:tap image:image